# How to play two pairs when flop is connected?

Tags: nlhe, online, cash-game, no-limit, all-in

Recently I had following hand. I was playing 6 players money `1/2$` NLH game  I had K♥J♠ in `SL`position. The player just before me made standard **3BB** bet I called. Every one else folded.

Then the flop came with K♣Q♥J⋄ rainbow. I had no idea if I should play it as if I had the best hand or rather with caution of the opponent hit Straight. I played following way on the Flop. I have checked, my opponent made 50% pot bet. Then I have reraised twice and he called.

On the Turn it came 7♣ and we went to all in. My opponent had k7o. The river was 4⋄ so I won the pot but still wondering whether I have played it correctly. Can you tell me how (and why) I should play this hand?

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, so I'll make it a comment. The villain's raising range from the cutoff could be a lot wider than just premium hands that hit this flop. You have a much stronger range represented here pre-flop with your flat call from the button. He has more reason to be concerned about your hand than you have about his.

Comment: I'm confused about the flop action you describe. You say "I have checked." But the action should have been on him first, because you say you're on the button. So, if you checked then he wouldn't have a chance to bet. Can you clarify the betting action here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the way you played this hand, I think you did just fine.

Your thinking is along the right lines - that flop is going to hit your opponents range a good part of the time. Fortunately for you, you have two pair, which is great! You check-raised on the flop and you got your opponent to call - that's a great move! Remember, the point of poker is **not** to win the pot - ***the point of poker is to cause players to make mistakes against you!*** And you managed to do that in this scenario, so I think you played the hand just fine.

Keep it up, this type of thinking/playing in poker will serve you just fine.

Comment: I don't disagree that a check-raise is ok here, but you can't check-raise from the button, so there are inconsistencies in the action.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer you're right. Either the action is wrong or the OP is getting confused on position names. I think my answer assumed that he meant small blind or big blind and not the button or the flop action is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You sound a bit paranoid. KJ with KQJ gives you a v.good 2 pair, normally you would be ecstatic, so why think any differently? What's to be scared of - KK unlikely, so either QQ or AX. If opp had either, he wouldn't have bet 50% pot, it would of been check or Pot, so by this stage you know you are ahead. You hit lucky with the 7, if you each had had more chips, AI might not of occured, so perhaps you should be asking yourself if you could have taken as much with the hindsight that opp also hit 2pair.

Answer (score 0):

I think you played fine. Against a "sounder" player, I would have folded the 3 BB bet (he might have had KQ), but this one raised with a weaker hand than your KJ off. This raise did have the effect of inducing others to fold, perhaps one with e.g a KQ.

When the flop hit you in two places, you were in "control" with your two pair. Your opponent would have the straight with only AT or T9, and should not have raised with the latter hand at least (and possibly not even with the former). The other hand that would have left you at at a disadvantage was KQ, but he didn't have that either. Nothing changed on the turn or the river, so you won with your two pair.